# How do I add links to each row of a table using this set up in d3 js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, html-table

I have set up a table using d3 js that successfully displays a saved csv file, called data.csv, in my html like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
            d3.text("/Users/cool_stuff/data.csv", function(data) {

                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("#meowwoof")
                    .selectAll("tr")
                        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                        .append("tr")

                    .selectAll("td")
                        .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) {
                              return d;
                            }
                        );
            });


 </script>


<tbody id="meowwoof">

</tbody>
```

This works great but I would like to add so if the user clicks on any row, it links so some URL that is, for example:

```
https://www.google.com/ + *value in first column of the given row thye clicked on*
```

I have found a few examples talking about how to do this, but they are for different initial set ups than what I am doing and thus they do not translate, and I am JS noob which makes it even harder to fit the explanations into my own setup

This is an example answer to a similar but different question I have not been able to figure out how to port:

[d3 adding html links to a column of data in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977234/d3-adding-html-links-to-a-column-of-data-in-a-table)

Comment: you can add a click handler to the `tr` element, in the handler search the first `td` and change `window.location`, you can change the pointer for a `tr` by CSS to show you can click on it

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you can attach a click event handler and redirect the user to the corresponding link

```
 var container = d3.select("#meowwoof")
                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")
                    .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; })
                    .enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function(d) {
                          return d;
                        }
                    )
                    .on('click',d=>{
                        // Assuming parsedCsv contains and d is a link
                        window.location.href = d;
                    })
```